# python 3 list in one long strand

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
grid = [['.','.','0','0','.','0','0','.','.'],
        ['.','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','.'],
        ['.','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','.'],
        ['.','.','0','0','0','0','0','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','0','0','0','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','0','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']]
print(grid)
```

**Result:**

```
[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'], ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'], ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'], ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
        [['.','.','0','0','.','0','0','.','.'],
         ['.','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','.'],
         ['.','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','.'],
         ['.','.','0','0','0','0','0','.','.'],
         ['.','.','.','0','0','0','.','.','.'],
         ['.','.','.','.','0','.','.','.','.'],
         ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']]
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Where did the sudden hostility come from?

Answer (score 5):

Use the built-in [pretty printer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(grid)
[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Comment: "You'll need to learn how pretty print works" college said. LITTLE DID THEY KNOW. import knows all.